# How to use namespace for a limited part of the code

Tags: c#, namespaces, using

I want to use `namespace System.Security.Cryptography` but only for a limited part of the code so that if I will try to use the namespace's`classes` or `function` out of the defined area it won't work. the result I'm expecting is something similar to the `using` statement in `types`, but with `namespaces`.

here is a sample code to showcase what I want:

```cs
using(System.Security.Cryptography;){
// namespace can be used from now on
            using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                UTF8Encoding utf8 =new UTF8Encoding();
                byte[] data = md5.ComputeHash(utf8.GetBytes(input));
                return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
            }
}
//now namespace can not be used- error if you are trying to use it
```

is it possible to do and how?

Comment: why not `using (var md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider()) {...}`? All you have to do is to put full name  - `System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider` - once.

Comment: not sure what you want, but maybe you can split your class into several files (in each use `partial class`), and then in every file you can use own set of `using`s

Comment: Not what you're looking for but you can use fully qualified names like "new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider()" for a similar effect.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko if I will do such thing, iw ill not have to write on the top of the program ( where ```using system``` is) ```using System.Security.Cryptography;```?

Comment: @avivgood2: yes, if you put `new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider()` you *don't have to write* `using System.Security.Cryptography;`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko you should post your comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using *full qualified name* `System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider` instead of `using` + short name (`MD5CryptoServiceProvider`):

```
  // var - let compiler derive the type
  using (var md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
  {
      UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
      byte[] data = md5.ComputeHash(utf8.GetBytes(input));
      return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
  }
```

If you do this, you'll not have to put `using System.Security.Cryptography;` at all

Answer (score 1):

Put it in using, or just use e.g.:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
```

Then no need for using.

My point is:

```
 using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
 {
     System.Text.UTF8Encoding utf8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
     byte[] data = md5.ComputeHash(utf8.GetBytes(input));
     return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
 }
```

Hope you get it now :)

Comment: tried it, it won't work. error: ```'MD5' does not contain a definition for 'MD5.CryptoService.Provider' ```